# How to combine multiple columns with similar names in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a similar structure to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a.1":[1, 2, 3], "a.2": ['mg', 'mg', 'mg'],
                   "b.1": [7, 8, 9], "b.2":['g', 'g', 'g'],
                   "c.1":[4, 5, 6], "c.2":["lb", "lb", "lb"]})
```

Basically, columns ending in `.1` are numerical values in terms of the units in columns ending in `.2`. I would like to combine the columns together in the pattern `a.1` with `a.2`, `b.1` with `b.2`, and `c.1` with `c.2` so that I have 3 columns with the numerical measurements and units combined rather than 6 columns.

I have only found how to combine multiple columns into one based on a condition, but I was wondering if there was a way to combine all the columns I want together at the same time instead of combining `a.1` with `a.2`, then `b.1` with `b.2`, and then `c.1` with `c.2`?

The expected output is:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["1mg", "2mg", "3mg"],
                    "b": ["7g", "8g", "9g"],
                    "c": ["4lb", "5lb", "6lb"]})
```

Comment: Can you add expected ouput to answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) with [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) for new `MultiIndex in columns` by split, so possible join DataFrames selected by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df1 = df.pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.str.split('.', expand=True), axis=1))
  
df2 = df1.xs('1', axis=1, level=1).astype(str).add(df1.xs('2', axis=1, level=1))
print (df2)
     a   b    c
0  1mg  7g  4lb
1  2mg  8g  5lb
2  3mg  9g  6lb
```

Another idea is group by splitted columns names with lambda function for join:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('.')[0], axis=1)
         .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:, 0].astype(str) + x.iloc[:, 1]))
print (df2)
     a   b    c
0  1mg  7g  4lb
1  2mg  8g  5lb
2  3mg  9g  6lb
```

Or:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('.')[0], axis=1)
         .apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).agg(''.join, axis=1)))
print (df2)
     a   b    c
0  1mg  7g  4lb
1  2mg  8g  5lb
2  3mg  9g  6lb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have the two `x.1` and `x.2` columns for every `x` (and no other columns), an efficient option could be direct slicing and [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) on the two parts:

```
out = (df.iloc[:, ::2].astype(str).add(df.iloc[:, 1::2].to_numpy(), axis=1)
         .rename(columns=lambda x: x.rsplit('.', 1)[0]) # keep only the "x" in "x.1"
      )
```

A bit more safe if you potentially have other columns, using [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to get the numeric and unit parts:

```
out = (df.filter(like='.1').astype(str).add(df.filter(like='.2').to_numpy(), axis=1)
         .rename(columns=lambda x: x.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
      )
```

Output:

```
     a   b    c
0  1mg  7g  4lb
1  2mg  8g  5lb
2  3mg  9g  6lb
```

*Note that the initial order of the columns is important, if the columns are not sorted `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)`.*